# Java EE 6 CDI: @Injected field of a @Injected field is null

Tags: java-ee-6, cdi, apache-tomee

I put together a small sample app here: https://github.com/lakamsani/cdi-nested

MyResource is a JAX-RS service into MyService is @Injected
MyDao is in-turn @Injected into MyService. When I run it (in TomEE 1.6.0.1),  MyDao is null inside the MyService instance injected to MyResource.  What do I need to do to make it work or is there another way of doing this (short of explicitly instantiating objects).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are seeing is a proxy instance of MyService being injected into MyResource.  Once you call a method on MyService, then a real instance is obtained from the correct context and it is in turn injected with MyDao.

If you really need a "real" instance of MyService when it is injected into MyResource, you may be able to make MyService a dependent scoped cdi bean and not a @Stateless EJB.

I may be misunderstanding why you need MyDao to be injected into MyService before any business methods are called.